# Match Values either using Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, data-preprocessing

I want to match the column 2 "ground_truth" values according to the values in column 1 "predicted_labels". The data is like in the picture below:

[image]

What I want it to be is shown the image below, keeping the word formats same.

[image]

Full data file can be accessed from this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13J57WJ3O6JYH5r2DYYohYl2LvhCPixy5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111798673819200913366&rtpof=true&sd=true

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this Excel addin (Fuzzy lookup) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: @P.b thanks it works.